# android:layout_height 50% of the screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, size, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I just implemented a ListView inside a LinearLayout, but I need to define the height of the LinearLayout (it has to be 50% of the screen height).

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget34"
    android:layout_width="300px"
    android:layout_height="235px"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_scanning_for"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_events"
        android:textSize="18sp"         
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_scanning_for"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is that possible?

I did something similar for a button and an EditText, but doesn't seem to work on Layouts.

This is my Code:

```
    //capture the size of the devices screen
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    double width = display.getWidth();

    //my EditText will be smaller than full screen (80%)        
    double doubleSize = (width/5)*4;
    int editTextSize = (int) doubleSize;

    //define the EditText 
    userName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    password = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.password);

    //set the size
    userName.setWidth(editTextSize);
    password.setWidth(editTextSize);
```

Comment: Have you tried using a RelativeLayout around the LinearLayout and size the RelativeLayout?

Comment: Can I enter a percent in the RelativeLayout height parameter?

Comment: use custom LayoutParams: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html with RelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29. set the height to display.getHeight()/2

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Set its `layout_height="0dp"`*, add a blank `View` beneath it (or blank `ImageView` or just a `FrameLayout`) with a `layout_height` also equal to `0dp`, and set both Views to have a `layout_weight="1"`

This will stretch each View equally as it fills the screen. Since both have the same weight, each will take 50% of the screen.

*See adamp's comment for why that works and other really helpful tidbits.

Comment: When you're using weight, remember that weight distributes *leftover* space after all child views have been measured. If you want to rely only on weight you need to set `layout_height="0dp"` instead of `wrap_content`. Also you can set `weightSum` on a LinearLayout explicitly rather than adding blank Views just to pad the total weight.

Comment: @adamp That's really excellent information that I didn't know. Many thanks.

Comment: what about width proportion balance?

Answer (score 8):

This is easy to do in xml. Set your top container to be a LinearLayout and set the orientation attribute as you wish. Then inside of that place two linearlayouts that both have "fill parent" on width and height. Finally, set the weigth attribute of those two linearlayouts to 1.

Answer (score 6):

This is my android:layout_height=50%
activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alipay_login"
        style="@style/loginType"
        android:background="#27b" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/taobao_login"
        style="@style/loginType"
        android:background="#ed6d00" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

style:

```
<style name="loginType">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">0.5</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

best way is use

layout_height="0dp"
layout_weight="0.5"

for example

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wvHelp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTEMP"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

WebView,TextView have 50% of the screen height

Answer (score 2):

To make sure the height of a view is 50% of the screen then we can create two sub LinearLayouts in a LinearLayout. Each of the child LinearLayout should have "**android:layout_weight**" of **0.5** to cover half the screen

the parent LinearLAyout should have "**android:orientation**" set to **vertical**

.

.

here is code for your reference....
this code contains two buttons of height half the screen

```
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="button1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="button2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of worked for me.
Though FAB doesn't float independently, but now it isn't getting pushed down.

Observe the weights given inside the LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/andsanddkasd">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/sharedResourcesRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget34"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_scanning_for"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_events"
        android:textSize="18sp"         
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_height="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_scanning_for"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also use ***dp*** instead ***px*** or read about it  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android).

Comment: Swap your height and weight values and this will be correct. ;)

Comment: Yes, it will be correct, but just for the current device resolution. What if the the test is on different resolution? Then he will get more or less then 50% depending on the new display resolution! And this is kinda tricky with static values for height/width! Learn how to use proportional dimensions for UI components!

Comment: weight and height still have exchanged values.

Answer (score 0):

it's so easy if you want divide your screen two part vertically ( top30% + bottom70%)

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutTop"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutBottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this feat, define a outer linear layout with a `weightSum={amount of weight to distribute}`.

it defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.Another example would be set weightSum=2, and if the two children set `layout_weight=1` then each would get 50% of the available space.

WeightSum is dependent on the amount of children in the parent layout.

Comment: children in this case can be any view group(FrameLayout) or any view such as imageView etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `android:weightSum="2"` on the parent layout combined with `android:layout_height="1"` on the child layout.

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
```