# how to make the size of a textview in proportion to the device's physical size

Tags: android, layout, textview, width

I've been digging around for a while about this issue. In my layout, I have a textview. How do I make the width of my textview's width half of the screen's physical width? Can I do it in the xml layout directly or I should have a function in the java code,which gets the physical size and set the textview's size one half of that? 
I don't care abou the resolution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794141/androidlayout-height-50-of-the-screen-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the layout_wheight attribute for yout TextView:

```
Android:layout_width="0dp"
Android:layout_weight=1
```

Use the same property (and same weight) on the layout you want to place on the side of your TextView, they will have both the same size = 1/2 of your physical screen.