# Android make canvas cover half screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app for drawing some simple lines in a canvas. I want the canvas to take up the top 50% of the screen, leaving the bottom 50% of the screen for buttons and what not. I am currently using `setContentView(canvas);` which makes it so that the canvas takes up 100% of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that extends View and do drawing inside that view on `onDraw()` method of that view. Add that view to your layout with any width or height you choose.

Comment: How do I add it to my layout with width and height of my choice?

Comment: Let's say you created a class MyView extends View in com.example.views java folder.You add this to xml as adding another view(TextView, imageView etc) <com.example.views.MyView> or instantiating it in runtime. You can search adding custom view on runtime or xml,  you will get lots of examples. Invoking myView.invalidate() invokes onDraw(Canvas canvas) of that view and you can draw anything you wish same way you draw to a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setContentView`, use your layout XML to create a view to hold the canvas as shown in [Error referencing an inner class View in layout/main.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098318/error-referencing-an-inner-class-view-in-layout-main-xml).

After that, it's a matter of using a technique in [android:layout_height 50% of the screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794141/androidlayout-height-50-of-the-screen-size) such as:

```xml
<LinearLayout ...>
<view
    class="com.example.foo.FooActivity$Drawer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can also use, say, `android:layout_weight="0.7"` and `"0.3"` to set the canvas/button container to 70% and 30% of the screen respectively.

Here's a minimal, complete example:

#### Layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f00"
>
    <view
        class="com.example.foo.FooActivity$Drawer"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:text="@string/start"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#f0f"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stop"
            android:text="@string/stop"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#f0f"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

#### Activity:

```java
package com.example.foo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class FooActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_foo);
    }

    public static class Drawer extends View {
        private static Paint paint;
        private static int viewWidth;
        private static int viewHeight;

        public Drawer(Context con, AttributeSet attr) {
            super(con, attr);
            paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        }

        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/9718512/6243352
        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld) {
            super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);
            viewWidth = xNew;
            viewHeight = yNew;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(final Canvas c) {
            super.onDraw(c);
            paint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
            int cx = viewWidth / 2;
            int cy = viewHeight / 2;
            c.drawCircle(cx, cy,viewWidth / 4, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Result:

[image: Android emulator screenshot showing half the top half of the screen as canvas and the bottom half a layout with buttons]